# ListView Inside ScrollView ignores layout ontop

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a ListView with a specific Height inside a ScrollView. I have other layouts above the Listview. However whenever I start the Activity, the Activity ignores the layouts ontop and scrolls directly to the listview.

Comment: you should never have listview within a scrollview

Comment: show your xml , so that we will help you in better way. BTW scrollview with list view is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have inserted : `<requestFocus />` by mistake inside listview as element.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I looked over my code, I dont have <requestFocus /> in my xml file. I inflated using a simple adapter, not sure if simple adapter is stealing focus.

Comment: I see whats the problem, the listview inside the scrollview is stealing the focus of the parent focus, all I had to do was to set focus to false in hard code.  listView.setFocusable(false);